# Monkey says no activities found

Tags: android, testing, android-activity, monkey

This used to work fine before in my setting, and now its giving this error even for a test application

the default manifest file is shown below;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

the image of the monkey output

[image]

the project name and directory matches if i am not wrong as shown here

[image]

I have no clue what i am doing wrong here.. help please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed eclipse in a new clean PC and now strangely it works..  so something in this installation is creating this error..  so now, to find out why...

Answer (score 0):

`-p <allowed-package-name>` in your case `-p com.example.test`

Comment: even with that I am getting the same message